# Deleting rows based on time interval in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have a dataframe with datetime timestamps (every 1 minute). I'd like to increase the time interval between rows to 5 minutes. Basically keep rows 0, 5, 10 etc and remove the rest. How would I do that?

```
Date                       Value
17/08/2017  04:00:00       0
17/08/2017  04:01:00       1
17/08/2017  04:02:00       2
17/08/2017  04:03:00       3
17/08/2017  04:04:00       4
17/08/2017  04:05:00       5
17/08/2017  04:06:00       6
17/08/2017  04:07:00       7
17/08/2017  04:08:00       8
17/08/2017  04:09:00       9
17/08/2017  04:10:00       10
```

Thanks

Comment: If your data starts with `00:00`, you can try `df.iloc[::5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly convert your date column to datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()` method(If its already of datetime then ignore this step):

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Finally You can do this by boolean masking:

```
newdf=df[df['Date'].dt.minute%5==0]
```

Now if you prints `newdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    Date                    Value
0   2017-08-17 04:00:00     0
5   2017-08-17 04:05:00     5
10  2017-08-17 04:10:00     10
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
newdf=newdf.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output of above code:

```
    Date                    Value
0   2017-08-17 04:00:00     0
1   2017-08-17 04:05:00     5
2   2017-08-17 04:10:00     10
```